# Sculpt mode remesh settings

Tags: sculpting, remesh

I have ran into a problem when sculpting. While sculpting I would hit the "Shift R" buttons to bring up a grid to see what size of remeshing I would do before I would "Ctrl R". Now when I "Shift R" it's blank until I go to 1.0 and turns it to a solid white square.

I can get the Grid to come back when I go back to factory settings, so What did I mess with? I would like to know so I don't do this again. I got projects that are so high in vertices that it crashes my computer as soon as I hit "Ctrl R".

Answer (score 0):

The new shortcut is just  <kbd>R</kbd> in *Sculpt Mode* to adjust the voxel size.